# Calculate days until your next birthday in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, logic

In the code above I wanted to calculate days until next birthday but the output is wrong. 
what it should be: 
My birth day: Feb 20 2002 => 203 days until my birthday(today is july 31 2018) 
what it actually is:
input: Feb 20 2002 => 179 days

My code:

```
import datetime


def get_user_birthday():
    year = int(input('When is your birthday? [YY] '))
    month = int(input('When is your birthday? [MM] '))
    day = int(input('When is your birthday? [DD] '))

    birthday = datetime.datetime(year,month,day)
    return birthday


def calculate_dates(original_date, now):
    date1 = now
    date2 = datetime.datetime(now.year, original_date.month, original_date.day)
    delta = date2 - date1
    days = delta.total_seconds() / 60 /60 /24

    return days


def show_info(self):
    pass



bd = get_user_birthday()
now = datetime.datetime.now()
c = calculate_dates(bd,now)
print(c)
```

Comment: None of the solutions offered below seems to take into account the rare case of someone being born on 29 February.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of problems:

1. Year must be specified as a complete integer, i.e. 2002, not 02 (or 2).
2. You need to check whether or not your birthdate has passed for this year.

Below is a solution which corrects these 2 issues. Given your input 20-Feb-2002 and today's date 31-Jul-2018, your next birthday is in 203 days' time.

In addition, note you can use the `days` attribute of a `timedelta` object, which will round down to 203 days and avoid the decimal precision.

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_user_birthday():
    year = int(input('When is your birthday? [YY] '))
    month = int(input('When is your birthday? [MM] '))
    day = int(input('When is your birthday? [DD] '))

    birthday = datetime(2000+year,month,day)
    return birthday

def calculate_dates(original_date, now):
    delta1 = datetime(now.year, original_date.month, original_date.day)
    delta2 = datetime(now.year+1, original_date.month, original_date.day)
    
    return ((delta1 if delta1 > now else delta2) - now).days

bd = get_user_birthday()
now = datetime.now()
c = calculate_dates(bd, now)

print(c)

When is your birthday? [YY] 02
When is your birthday? [MM] 02
When is your birthday? [DD] 20

113
```

Answer (score 4):

Think about what your `calculate_dates` function is doing.

You are getting your birthday, and then looking at how far the current time is from that birthday in the current year. Hence, what you are doing is finding the number of days to your birthday *in the current year*, whether or not it has past.

For example, take your birthday February 20th. Your `date2` will be `2018-2-20` rather than `2019-2-20`.

You can fix this by checking whether or not the day has already passed in this year.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for both cases (next birthday this or next year)
Using two digits for years is probably always a bad idea, especially for birthdays ;)

```
def get_days_until_birthday(birthday: date, today: date) -> int:
    this_year = (date(today.year, birthday.month, birthday.day) - today).days
    if this_year >= 0:
        return this_year

    next_year = (date(today.year+1, birthday.month, birthday.day) - today).days
    return next_year
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would calculate the days until birthday:

```
from datetime import datetime


def get_user_birthday():
    year = int(input('When is your birthday? [YY] '))
    month = int(input('When is your birthday? [MM] '))
    day = int(input('When is your birthday? [DD] '))

    birthday = datetime(year,month,day)
    return birthday


def calculate_dates(birthyday):
    now = datetime.now()
    birthday = datetime(now.year, birthday.month, birthday.day)
    return (birthday - now.today()).days + 1


bd = get_user_birthday()
c = calculate_dates(bd)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import time

today = date.today()

def user_birthday():
    year = int(input('When is your birthday? [YY] '))
    month = int(input('When is your birthday? [MM] '))
    day = int(input('When is your birthday? [DD] '))

    birthday = datetime(year,month,day)
    return birthday

def calculate_dates(birthday):
    today == date.fromtimestamp(time.time())
    birthday = date(today.year, birthday.month, birthday.day)
    if birthday < today:
        birthday = birthday.replace(year=today.year + 1)
        return birthday
    else:
        return birthday
    
bday = user_birthday()
t = calculate_dates(bday)
time_to_birthday = abs(t-today)
days=str(time_to_birthday.days)
print("Time to Birthday is :" + days + " days")
```

This above program will tell you days regardless if it is coming this year or past this year (in which case it will calculate for next year)